# Java - use jsonPath to update Json based on current value

Tags: java, jsonpath, jayway

I managed to update a json object using a jsonPath with this code

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{\"data\":[{\"city\":\"New York\",\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":31},{\"city\":\"Paris\",\"name\":\"Jack\",\"age\":12}]}");
DocumentContext doc = JsonPath.parse(json.toString())
                .set("$..name","newName");
System.out.println("doc.jsonString() = " + doc.jsonString());
```

outputs:

```
doc.jsonString() = {"data":[{"city":"New York","name":"newName","age":31},{"city":"Paris","name":"newName","age":12}]}
```

Now I would like to update the value depending on the old value (by applying a function on the old value)
Something like

```
DocumentContext doc = JsonPath.parse(json.toString())
                .set("$..name",upper(oldValue))
                .set("$..age", oldValue+10);
```

That would result in the following json

```
 doc.jsonString() = doc.jsonString() = {"data":[{"city":"New York","name":"JOHN","age":41},{"city":"Paris","name":"JACK","age":22}]}
```

Does someone know how I can manage to reference the old value like that ?
Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the map function of the DocumentContext class like the example below:

```
DocumentContext json = JsonPath.using(configuration).parse(jsonStr);
DocumentContext result = json.map("$..name", (currentValue, configuration) -> {
    return currentValue.toString().toUpperCase();
});
System.out.println(result.jsonString());
```

That example change the value to uppercase.

Try to check about it in the [Jsonpath DocumentContext  class documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/2.2.0/com/jayway/jsonpath/WriteContext.html#set-com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath-java.lang.Object-).

Answer (score 0):

You can use parse and set functions of JsonPath.

example:

```
public static String replaceOldValueVithNewValueforGivenPath(String jsonBody, String path, String newValue)
{
   // validateJsonInput(jsonBody);
    try {
        return JsonPath.parse(jsonBody).set(path,newValue).jsonString();
    } catch (PathNotFoundException var3) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No results for path: " + path);
    }
}
```

Comment: import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath; Add this import if not added.